Define an high dimensional system with stable limit cycle
apologies for the question, but I'm very new to the field of control systems.
I need to define a system that exhibits a stable limit cycle in a high-dimensional space (~300 dimensions). I'm not even sure if such a system can be defined, but it would be great to get help from someone with more experience.
From what I understand so far, to have a limit cycle, the system should have a set of unstable equilibrium points. My go-to strategy will be to define a potential function $V(x)$ such that all the equilibrium points are local maxima of this potential, but i have no idea on how define such potential. My dynamic should be something like $\dot x = - \nabla V(x) $
Thanks in advance for any help!

Some additional context on the purpose of this:
 I'm working on dynamic fusion, with the goal of mapping one dynamical system to another using neural networks. The reference system should serve as a model for my network to replicate. Given an unknown system X and a reference system Y, my aim is to impose the properties of system Y onto system X. For now, the goal is to impose a limit cycle on the original system, and any stable limit cycle should (in principle) work. For this reason, I don't have specific requirements for the limit cycle

Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about how to ask a good question.

What should be the dimensions of the manifold that the limit cycle converges to?

Can you work in spherical coordinates? If so, it is easy to define a closed,  stable trajectory in such coordinates.

@KBS I can try, i don't have any specific requirement for now. I'm adding some context on the post, explaining what my goal is. Could you give me some clarification on how I could use spherical coordinates?

@KwinvanderVeen In principle, any manifold should work, I'm adding extra info on the post for clarify what my goal is and how i intended to use such system
